# Integrating google map api key in my android project

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

when I update the google map API key in my android studio project it will not list the destination address when I try to type the location

Comment: That means your API will be invalid.

Comment: check whether you have enable required APIs for this key

Comment: sir, I again created a google map API key ..and I added my API key and package name on the google console. but when I using this API key, the map or location cannot show in my application

Comment: may be your internet is slow

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for this

- Please verify you API key and package name you have added in
  google console.
- Please verify your android manifest configuration.
- Make sure you have enabled Map API in console
- Please check log-cat for getting more information related to the
  issue.

even after you cannot find any issue. please go through this link [Google maps Android](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)